# How to raise double to array powers in Eigen

Tags: c++, arrays, eigen

I have a very simple problem that should have a simple answer as well, but so far no luck.

I need to raise a double value to an array of integer powers, in c++ this would look something like

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
{
    y[i] = pow(delta, l[i]);
}
```

But in Eigen I have tried a number of variants on this theme, without success.

I have an `Eigen::ArrayXi l_intE` which maps an STL vector `l_int`.

This doesn't work:

```
Eigen::pow(double, l_intE)
```

since the `pow()` function wants an array as the first input, and then to raise the array to a constant power.

One nasty workaround that I was able to get working (this can't be the right way) is to do this:

```
(log(delta)*l_doubleE).exp()
```

which does the conversion

```
pow(delta,L) -> exp(L*log(delta))
```

and I have to convert the integers to doubles.  This can't help performance either since pow(double, int) is *significantly* faster than pow(double, double) in general.  Although, maybe that isn't true with SSE in Eigen?

Anyway, clarity here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you tried using powf?

Comment: Not sure I understand your comment.  powf is only for pow(float, float) or pow(float, int), right?

Answer (score 1):

What about simply multiplying each `y[i]` with itself `l[i]` times?

```
y.fill(1);
for (ArrayXi e = l; (e>0).any(); e -= 1)
    y = (e>0).select(delta*y, y);
```

Note that after every multiplication we subtract one from the exponents and exit the loop when all of them are zero or less. Since this algorithm modifies the array of exponents in order to keep track of the number of multiplications, we copy it in the initialization clause of the for loop. If it is fine to destroy `l` along the way, this copy could be omitted.

Comment: add some explanation too with the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with the following code:

```
Eigen::ArrayXd N = Eigen::pow(2, Eigen::ArrayXd::LinSpaced(10, 1, 10));
```

The array N will contain: 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024

Comment: When was this capability added to Eigen?  Obviously the original question is now 5 years old.

Comment: @ibell I don't know. But the question appears on Google very high on the list, so a recent answer is not bad.